# Problem where 5 Face Flows are Meeting at 1 Vertex

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, shrinkwrap

I Think Images WIll be Best... SO those goes... [.blend file - Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ZgezEOf6TCoiJyAjIubFYRMTPYx-AI8/view?usp=sharing)

You can see How the Mesh is getting Bad where that 5 face Joint vertex is....

I don't wanna describe anymore, you can see for yourself in the image... and in the blend file

But it is Like I can't post the question

[image: IMAGE001]
[image: ScreenShoot 2]

Comment: A 5 edge vertex such as this is known as a "pole" and is sometimes a necessary part of making a mesh.However, as you are experiencing, they can cause shading issues, especially when placed on a curved surface that has smooth shading applied, or near edges. The best solution in these cases (if the pole cannot be avoided) is to move the pole closer to the center of a flat face. The other issue you have, that is also likely causing shading issues, is the two edge loops that terminate into the side of a quad a little down and to the right of pole you have highlighted in your second image.

Comment: I thought About that, Thank You Christopher... I decided That I would keep that in mind while modeling from the next time...